# python find dictionaries in list where certain key is not present

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a JSON string which I parse into a list of dictionaries.

```
o='{"a": [{"a_a": "123-1", "a_b": "exists"}, {"a_a": "123-2"}, {"a_a": "123-3"}]}'
o=json.loads(o)
```

What would be the best way now to get the dictionaries where `a_b` is not present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach, using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
res = [d for d in o["a"] if "a_b" not in d]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'a_a': '123-2'}, {'a_a': '123-3'}]
```

Or the equivalent, less *pythonic*, for-loop:

```
res = []
for d in o["a"]:
    if "a_b" not in d:
        res.append(d)
```

A third approach, even less *pythonic* (in my opinion), is to use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) with a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lambda) function:

```
res = list(filter(lambda x: "a_b" not in x, o["a"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension, as there could be several matches, the output is a list:

```
out = [d for d in o['a'] if 'a_b' not in d]
```

Output: `[{'a_a': '123-1', 'a_b': 'exists'}]`

If you expect at most one match (or only care about the first one):

```
next((d for d in o['a'] if 'a_b' not in d), None)
```

Output: `{'a_a': '123-2'}`

*NB. You can also use another default value in `next` (not necessarily None).*

Comment: Thanks @Dani I had misread (phone screen!)